# No subject alternative names present add exception

Tags: java, web-services, ssl

I'm using Java SE6 Mustang and I'm trying to connect to a Web Service that uses SSL. I created the Web Service Client with wsimport, can I ignore the Exception:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present

Comment: are you sure that the cn in the server's certificate matches the address of the server?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot ignore this exception.

If you get this error while creating client, you can download WSDL and execute generation by using it. Something like this. But i not check it.

```
wsimport -p com.test -wsdllocation https://192.168.1.200:8443/services/ws/service?wsdl service.wsdl
```

But if you get this error while accessing to web service, you can disable hostname chekcing.
Here is an example to disable hostname checking.

```
    static{
    javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(
    new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier(){

        public boolean verify(String hostname,
                javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
            System.out.println("Verifying hostname: " + hostname);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```